# SP2013: Search Service Application failed with exception System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I just installed SharePoint 2013 standalone mode on a computer. Everything went well and the installation finished successfully. However, I checked the Event Log and I found the following error showing up every minute. I just wonder if anyone here could help?

```
The administration component for application Search Service Application failed with exception System.InvalidOperationException: This operation uses the SharePoint Administration service (spadminV4), which could not be contacted.  If the service is stopped or disabled, start it and try the operation again.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServer.AddMemberToLocalWorkerProcessGroup(String userName)
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.AnalyticsServiceAdministration.ProvisionServiceInstance(SearchServiceApplication app)
    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
```

Comment: Update: After I reinstall SharePoint 2013 in farm mode, everything works fine. It seems like the code path for standalone mode hasn't been tested much. So my recommendation for those who wants to evaluate or develop SP2013, it's best to install it the same way as how it will be minimally installed on a production site. That is a single server farm mode with a separated MS SQL instance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you enabled search service application on your web application and it's not configured properly, you might would like to disable it for your web application or re configure it, I installed SharePoint 2013 but never messed around with search services so never received that error.

hope it helps, and let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thanks TimeToShine for a swift response. The SP2013 seems to be much differ from SP2010 and I have no idea how to temporary disable the Search Service Application to see if the problem will be gone after the suspect error source is disabled.

Can you guide me to temporary disable the search service, please?

Comment: I don't have any SharePoint 2013 machine so that I can exactly tell you what to do but if you go to Application Management and then Manage Service and then disable it or alternatively, Go to System settings and then Manage services running on this server/farm and try to disable it, hope it helps